# Cannot resolve class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart when upgrading from 3.0.2 to 3.1.0

Tags: android, mpchart

I'm maintaining an app written in 2019 (already used AndroidX). I'm curious what if I upgrade the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) from v3.0.2 to to 3.1.0?

**selling_summary_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    tools:context=".ui.home.statistics.SellingSummaryActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/bar_chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "xxxxx_for_android"
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

include ':app'
```

Eventually, when loading selling_summary_activity.xml, Android Studio (I'm on Flamingo) complains:

> Class referenced in the layout file,
> com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart, was not found in the
> project or the libraries

Cleaning, rebuilding, invalidate caches and sync project with Gradle a few times, even restarting Android Studio doesn't solve the issue. But reverting MPAndroidChart to v3.0.2 quickly solves it. What's wrong here? Perhaps I miss some additional settings to use the latest version?

Comment: We are using BarChart in pretty much the same setup (also from XML file with the same implementation dependency, though we have a multi-module project) on v3.1.0 without any problems so this is actually pretty weird. Can you access other charts? Did you setup a small test project.
Note that MPAndroidChart project is pretty much dead.

Comment: I created a small Android Java project (the only 3rd party dependency is MPAndroidChart 3.1.0), and it worked fine. No issue with running code examples found online. No idea why it doesn't work on this particular project, perhaps wrong config in gradle or something else...